# creating dynamic kibana index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have data that is being indexed in elasticsearch that is date based. The form is "mydata-YYYY.MM.DD". I don't want to create a new index each day in Kibana, and have looked at the rolling index but cannot get the API to work. I have the following python script to interact with the API:

```
import requests
import json


url = "http://localhost:9200/"

body = {"conditions": {"max_age": "1d"}}

r = requests.post(url + "alias1/_rollover/mydata-*", json=body)

print(r.json())
```

This is yielding:

```
{'error': {'reason': 'source alias does not exist', 'root_cause': [{'reason': 'source alias does not exist', 'type': 'illegal_argument_exception'}], 'type': 'illegal_argument_exception'}, 'status': 400}
```

The documentation on their website that I am following makes it seem that this should be possible:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-rollover-index.html

Comment: What do you mean by `cannot get the API to work`? What have you tried and what is the error?

Comment: Is that `mydata-*`?